How to derive the three-dimensional diffraction experiment by using quantum mechanics?
I'm reading Feynman's "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals," and in section 3-2, it discusses the one-dimensional case of diffraction. It seems that this method can be easily extended to three dimensions. For instance, if we consider a particle at time $T$ in a certain region $(X \pm a, Y \pm b, Z \pm c)$ along the $X,Y,Z$ directions, and then consider the situation at time $T + t$. It appears that the three-dimensional propagator is the product of the one-dimensional propagators.
But my confusion is that, in reality, there isn't a particle precisely localized at $(0,0,0)$. So, is it sufficient to just calculate the propagator to obtain the correct conclusion? I am trying to do the following: assume an initial state $|\Psi\rangle$, then multiply it by the momentum shift operator to construct initial states with all possible momenta  $$
e^{i\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{R}}|\Psi\rangle
$$ assuming the particle density is $ n $ in each momentum interval. This way, we can integrate to obtain the number density of particles arriving near $\mathbf r_B $
$$
\int d^3 u\, n|\langle \mathbf{r}_B|U(t_B,t_A)e^{i\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{R}}|\Psi\rangle|^2\\
=\int d^3 u\, n\,\left|\int d^3 r_A \, K(\mathbf{r}_B,\mathbf{r}_A)e^{i\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{r_A}}\Psi(\mathbf{r}_A)\right|^2\\
=\int d^3 u \, n\int d^3 r_A\, K(\mathbf{r}_B,\mathbf{r}_A)e^{i\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{r_A}}\Psi(\mathbf{r}_A) \int d^3 r'_A\, K^*(\mathbf{r}_B,\mathbf{r}'_A)e^{-i\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{r'_A}}\Psi^*(\mathbf{r}'_A)\\
=
n\int d^3 r_A\, |K(\mathbf{r}_B,\mathbf{r}_A)|^2|\Psi(\mathbf{r}_A)|^2
$$
In the above expression, I first try to integrate over $\mathbf{u}$ ,  which results in $\delta(\mathbf{r}_A-\mathbf{r}'_{A})$. Is my calculation correct? This result seems to indicate that when $|\Psi(\mathbf{r}_A)|^2$ is sufficiently localized near $\mathbf{r=0}$,  it becomes $n|K|^2$.Is this the reason we can directly use the propagator to calculate it? Another question is, in an actual diffraction experiment, are particles emitted in every direction and at every speed as described?

Are you asking about optical diffraction? That's a bit of a problem. Quantum mechanics is usually formulated in a unitary way, while diffraction is not unitary. In a classical diffraction experiment the surfaces absorb energy, i.e. not every quantum system in our ensemble leads to a detection of that energy in the end. I don't know how one would shoehorn that into the path integral. At this level of description the only self-consistent physics is the scattering of interacting quantum fields, which is unitary.

https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1001&context=physicsbatelaan
